# html hr is not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have this code, with some `<hr>` tags at the end with the paragraphs with a class. The problem is they are going berserk and not working properly. It's not positioning after the `<p>` tags as it is supposed to be the third and fourth tag are ok but the first and second's `<hr>` tags are just below the third and fourth `<p>` and `<hr>`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hDrk.png

here's the image of the result of the code if anyone wants to see

```css
#text {
  color: rgb(134, 47, 215);
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.align-horizontal-a {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.align-horizontal-b {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.align-horizontal-c {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.align-horizontal-d {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.align-horizontal-a,
.align-horizontal-b,
.align-horizontal-c,
.align-horizontal-d {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 75px;
  left: 715px;
}

.align-horizontal-d:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.align-horizontal-c:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.align-horizontal-b:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.align-horizontal-a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vertical-aligned-item-a,
.vertical-aligned-item-b,
.vertical-aligned-item-c,
.vertical-aligned-item-d {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
}

.image-x-sign {
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 300px;
  display: none;
}

.none-display {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .vertical-aligned-item-a,
  .vertical-aligned-item-b,
  .vertical-aligned-item-c,
  .vertical-aligned-item-d,
  .none-display,
  .image-x-sign {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav width="100%">
  <div>
    <h3 id="text">WebDev.</h3>
    <hr>
    <p class="align-horizontal-a">Services</p>
    <p class="align-horizontal-b">Blog</p>
    <p class="align-horizontal-c">About</p>
    <p class="align-horizontal-d">Contact</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="x-sign.png" alt="x-sign" class="image-x-sign">
    <p class="vertical-aligned-item-a">Services</p>
    <hr class="none-display">
    <p class="vertical-aligned-item-b">Blog</p>
    <hr class="none-display">
    <p class="vertical-aligned-item-c">About</p>
    <hr class="none-display">
    <p class="vertical-aligned-item-d">Contact</p>
    <hr class="none-display">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `bottom: 90px;` in the styles for the selector of .vertical-aligned-item-a,
.vertical-aligned-item-b,
.vertical-aligned-item-c, and .vertical-aligned-item-d might fix your issue. Although I'm not getting the same result for a widescreen > 500px due to your media query. See if it helps!